# How do I use zlib within windows using CMake and Mingw?

Tags: windows, cmake, mingw, zlib, clion

My environment is using CLion, running CMake and Mingw.

I need to use zlib in my project, but I can't for the life of me get it to link in windows.

If I follow the solution of [this stackoverflow article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36126333/mingw-cmake-undefined-reference-to-zlib) , attempting to just build the zlib example binaries, with the exact cmakelists as in the mentioned article, I receive the error:

`Could NOT find ZLIB (missing: ZLIB_INCLUDE_DIR)`

I also was unable to find a precompiled binary for zlib on the official zlib website, which the zlib's own documentation states should exist on the site, so trying to just link that on my project has been difficult.

I did find some binaries, but on attempting to link them, (Which, I'm still trying to figure out how to link a dll with cmake, so that may be part of the issue), the make system just nopes out.

`mingw32-make.exe[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/CMinecraft.dir/rule] Error 2
mingw32-make.exe: *** [CMinecraft] Error 2
CMakeFiles\Makefile2:153: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/CMinecraft.dir/rule' failed`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! If you have problems with your code, **add the code into the question post** (in form of [mcve]) and provide description of what happens when you use it. If code cause building to fail, provide **exact error message** about that fail. Line `mingw32-make.exe[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/CMinecraft.dir/rule] Error 2` isn't descriptive, as it shows only that it was *some error*.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the feedback. I wasn't very specific about what I was using. The error I posted however was the exact error message I was receiving, and I certainly agree that it shows that _some_ error occured, but the compiler provided no additional information, which was part of my confusion and the reason for this question in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Personnaly for windows (VS 2015/2017 but should works with Mingw) I integrate it as CMake subproject using:

In your CMakeLists.txt:

```
if(NOT TARGET ZLIB::ZLIB)
  message(STATUS "Target ZLIB::ZLIB not found.")
  message(STATUS "Adding CMake Subproject: ZLIB...")
  # Download and unpack zlib at configure time
  configure_file(
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/zlib.CMakeLists.txt
    ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/zlib-download/CMakeLists.txt)
  execute_process(COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -G "${CMAKE_GENERATOR}" .
    RESULT_VARIABLE result
    WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/zlib-download)
  if(result)
    message(FATAL_ERROR "CMake step for zlib failed: ${result}")
  endif()
  execute_process(COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} --build .
    RESULT_VARIABLE result
    WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/zlib-download)
  if(result)
    message(FATAL_ERROR "Build step for zlib failed: ${result}")
  endif()

  add_subdirectory(
    ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/zlib-src
    ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/zlib-build)
  message(STATUS "Adding CMake Subproject: ZLIB...DONE")
endif()
```

with zlib.CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)

# simplify variable expansion
cmake_policy(SET CMP0053 NEW)
cmake_policy(SET CMP0010 NEW)

project(zlib-download NONE)

include(ExternalProject)
ExternalProject_Add(zlib_project
  GIT_REPOSITORY "https://github.com/madler/zlib.git"
  GIT_TAG "v1.2.11"
  SOURCE_DIR "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/zlib-src"
  BINARY_DIR "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/zlib-build"
  UPDATE_COMMAND ""
  PATCH_COMMAND git apply "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/patches/zlib.patch"
  CONFIGURE_COMMAND ""
  BUILD_COMMAND ""
  INSTALL_COMMAND ""
  TEST_COMMAND ""
  LOG_DOWNLOAD ON
)
```

and patches/zlib.path:

```
diff --git a/CMakeLists.txt b/CMakeLists.txt
index 0fe939d..5f25cce 100644
--- a/CMakeLists.txt
+++ b/CMakeLists.txt
@@ -1,24 +1,23 @@
-cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.4.4)
-set(CMAKE_ALLOW_LOOSE_LOOP_CONSTRUCTS ON)
+cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.12)
+cmake_policy(SET CMP0048 NEW)
+project(zlib VERSION 1.2.11.1 LANGUAGES C)

-project(zlib C)
+option(ASM686 "Enable building i686 assembly implementation" OFF)
+option(AMD64 "Enable building amd64 assembly implementation" OFF)

-set(VERSION "1.2.11")
+include(GNUInstallDirs)
+set(INSTALL_BIN_DIR "${CMAKE_INSTALL_BINDIR}" CACHE PATH "Installation directory for executables")
+set(INSTALL_LIB_DIR "${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}" CACHE PATH "Installation directory for libraries")
+set(INSTALL_INC_DIR "${CMAKE_INSTALL_INCLUDEDIR}" CACHE PATH "Installation directory for headers")

-option(ASM686 "Enable building i686 assembly implementation")
-option(AMD64 "Enable building amd64 assembly implementation")
-
-set(INSTALL_BIN_DIR "${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/bin" CACHE PATH "Installation directory for executables")
-set(INSTALL_LIB_DIR "${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/lib" CACHE PATH "Installation directory for libraries")
-set(INSTALL_INC_DIR "${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/include" CACHE PATH "Installation directory for headers")
-set(INSTALL_MAN_DIR "${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/share/man" CACHE PATH "Installation directory for manual pages")
-set(INSTALL_PKGCONFIG_DIR "${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/share/pkgconfig" CACHE PATH "Installation directory for pkgconfig (.pc) files")
+set(INSTALL_MAN_DIR "${CMAKE_INSTALL_MANDIR}" CACHE PATH "Installation directory for manual pages")
+set(INSTALL_PKGCONFIG_DIR "${CMAKE_INSTALL_DATADIR}/pkgconfig" CACHE PATH "Installation directory for pkgconfig (.pc) files")

 include(CheckTypeSize)
 include(CheckFunctionExists)
 include(CheckIncludeFile)
 include(CheckCSourceCompiles)
-enable_testing()
+include(CTest)

 check_include_file(sys/types.h HAVE_SYS_TYPES_H)
 check_include_file(stdint.h    HAVE_STDINT_H)
@@ -63,7 +62,6 @@ if(MSVC)
     set(CMAKE_DEBUG_POSTFIX "d")
     add_definitions(-D_CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE)
     add_definitions(-D_CRT_NONSTDC_NO_DEPRECATE)
-    include_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})
 endif()

 if(NOT CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR STREQUAL CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR)
@@ -83,7 +81,6 @@ configure_file( ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/zlib.pc.cmakein
        ${ZLIB_PC} @ONLY)
 configure_file(    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/zconf.h.cmakein
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/zconf.h @ONLY)
-include_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR} ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR})


 #============================================================================
@@ -132,9 +129,9 @@ endif()
 if(CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUCC)
     if(ASM686)
         set(ZLIB_ASMS contrib/asm686/match.S)
-    elseif (AMD64)
+           elseif(AMD64)
         set(ZLIB_ASMS contrib/amd64/amd64-match.S)
-    endif ()
+    endif()

    if(ZLIB_ASMS)
        add_definitions(-DASMV)
@@ -143,20 +140,20 @@ if(CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUCC)
 endif()

 if(MSVC)
-    if(ASM686)
+   if(ASM686)
        ENABLE_LANGUAGE(ASM_MASM)
-        set(ZLIB_ASMS
+       set(ZLIB_ASMS
            contrib/masmx86/inffas32.asm
            contrib/masmx86/match686.asm
-       )
-    elseif (AMD64)
+           )
+   elseif(AMD64)
        ENABLE_LANGUAGE(ASM_MASM)
-        set(ZLIB_ASMS
+       set(ZLIB_ASMS
            contrib/masmx64/gvmat64.asm
            contrib/masmx64/inffasx64.asm
-       )
-    endif()
-
+           )
+       # set(ZLIB_SRCS ${ZLIB_SRCS} contrib/masmx64/inffas8664.c)
+   endif()
    if(ZLIB_ASMS)
        add_definitions(-DASMV -DASMINF)
    endif()
@@ -184,9 +181,25 @@ if(MINGW)
 endif(MINGW)

 add_library(zlib SHARED ${ZLIB_SRCS} ${ZLIB_ASMS} ${ZLIB_DLL_SRCS} ${ZLIB_PUBLIC_HDRS} ${ZLIB_PRIVATE_HDRS})
+target_include_directories(zlib PUBLIC
+   $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}>
+   $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}>
+   $<INSTALL_INTERFACE:include>)
+set_target_properties(zlib PROPERTIES
+   DEFINE_SYMBOL ZLIB_DLL
+   SOVERSION 1)
+
 add_library(zlibstatic STATIC ${ZLIB_SRCS} ${ZLIB_ASMS} ${ZLIB_PUBLIC_HDRS} ${ZLIB_PRIVATE_HDRS})
-set_target_properties(zlib PROPERTIES DEFINE_SYMBOL ZLIB_DLL)
-set_target_properties(zlib PROPERTIES SOVERSION 1)
+target_include_directories(zlibstatic PUBLIC
+   $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}>
+   $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}>
+   $<INSTALL_INTERFACE:include>)
+
+if(BUILD_SHARED_LIBS)
+   add_library(ZLIB::ZLIB ALIAS zlib)
+else()
+   add_library(ZLIB::ZLIB ALIAS zlibstatic)
+endif()

 if(NOT CYGWIN)
     # This property causes shared libraries on Linux to have the full version
@@ -197,6 +210,7 @@ if(NOT CYGWIN)
     # This has no effect with MSVC, on that platform the version info for
     # the DLL comes from the resource file win32/zlib1.rc
     set_target_properties(zlib PROPERTIES VERSION ${ZLIB_FULL_VERSION})
+    set_target_properties(zlibstatic PROPERTIES VERSION ${ZLIB_FULL_VERSION})
 endif()

 if(UNIX)
@@ -210,12 +224,30 @@ elseif(BUILD_SHARED_LIBS AND WIN32)
     set_target_properties(zlib PROPERTIES SUFFIX "1.dll")
 endif()

-if(NOT SKIP_INSTALL_LIBRARIES AND NOT SKIP_INSTALL_ALL )
+#if(WIN32)
+#  add_definitions(-DZLIB_WINAPI)
+#endif()
+
+if(NOT SKIP_INSTALL_LIBRARIES AND NOT SKIP_INSTALL_ALL)
     install(TARGETS zlib zlibstatic
-        RUNTIME DESTINATION "${INSTALL_BIN_DIR}"
-        ARCHIVE DESTINATION "${INSTALL_LIB_DIR}"
-        LIBRARY DESTINATION "${INSTALL_LIB_DIR}" )
-endif()
+           EXPORT ZLIBTargets
+           RUNTIME DESTINATION "${INSTALL_BIN_DIR}"
+           ARCHIVE DESTINATION "${INSTALL_LIB_DIR}"
+           LIBRARY DESTINATION "${INSTALL_LIB_DIR}")
+       install(EXPORT ZLIBTargets
+           NAMESPACE ZLIB::
+           DESTINATION lib/cmake/ZLIB)
+       include(CMakePackageConfigHelpers)
+       write_basic_package_version_file("${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/ZLIBConfigVersion.cmake"
+           VERSION ${PROJECT_VERSION}
+           COMPATIBILITY SameMajorVersion)
+       file(WRITE "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/ZLIBConfig.cmake"
+           "include(\"\${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/ZLIBTargets.cmake\")"
+           )
+       install(FILES "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/ZLIBConfig.cmake"
+           "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/ZLIBConfigVersion.cmake"
+           DESTINATION lib/cmake/ZLIB)
+   endif()
 if(NOT SKIP_INSTALL_HEADERS AND NOT SKIP_INSTALL_ALL )
     install(FILES ${ZLIB_PUBLIC_HDRS} DESTINATION "${INSTALL_INC_DIR}")
 endif()
@@ -229,21 +261,22 @@ endif()
 #============================================================================
 # Example binaries
 #============================================================================
-
-add_executable(example test/example.c)
-target_link_libraries(example zlib)
-add_test(example example)
-
-add_executable(minigzip test/minigzip.c)
-target_link_libraries(minigzip zlib)
-
-if(HAVE_OFF64_T)
-    add_executable(example64 test/example.c)
-    target_link_libraries(example64 zlib)
-    set_target_properties(example64 PROPERTIES COMPILE_FLAGS "-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64")
-    add_test(example64 example64)
-
-    add_executable(minigzip64 test/minigzip.c)
-    target_link_libraries(minigzip64 zlib)
-    set_target_properties(minigzip64 PROPERTIES COMPILE_FLAGS "-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64")
+if(BUILD_TESTING)
+   add_executable(example test/example.c)
+   target_link_libraries(example zlib)
+   add_test(example example)
+
+   add_executable(minigzip test/minigzip.c)
+   target_link_libraries(minigzip zlib)
+
+   if(HAVE_OFF64_T)
+       add_executable(example64 test/example.c)
+       target_link_libraries(example64 zlib)
+       set_target_properties(example64 PROPERTIES COMPILE_FLAGS "-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64")
+       add_test(example64 example64)
+
+       add_executable(minigzip64 test/minigzip.c)
+       target_link_libraries(minigzip64 zlib)
+       set_target_properties(minigzip64 PROPERTIES COMPILE_FLAGS "-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64")
+   endif()
 endif()
```

src: https://github.com/google/or-tools/tree/master/cmake/external
ref: ExternalProject tricks https://crascit.com/2015/07/25/cmake-gtest/

ZLIB PR #337: https://github.com/madler/zlib/pull/337

Comment: Hi! I appreciate your answer, but I was trying to avoid having to compile zlib myself, which seems to be discouraged by the zlib dev team. The links you provided though will be helpful with some ideas I had in cleaning up my cmake file! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I ended up finding the fix.

CMake had no idea where to find zlib, even if it was in the current working directory. Luckily, MinGW comes with it as part of it's binaries, and it can be pointed to and used.

```
set(ZLIB_INCLUDE_DIR "C:/MinGW/bin")
find_package(ZLIB REQUIRED)
if (ZLIB_FOUND)
    include_directories(${ZLIB_INCLUDE_DIRS})
endif()

target_link_libraries(CMinecraft ${ZLIB_LIBRARIES})
```

Comment: Did you try (don't know if it works) to use `set ZLIB_INCLUDE_DIR="C:\MinGW\bin"` or set path in order to have a portable CMake ? (i.e. not everyone hase installed MinGW...  and at this location...)